# Can an SCV repair a Protoss ally's structures?

Tags: starcraft-2

- In a 2vs2, 3vs3, or 4vs4 matchup
- In SC2 Wings of Liberty
- Repair structures, not units.

Comment: Remember that medivacs can heal your biological protoss units.

Answer (score 13):

SCVs can repair anything that is deemed 'mechanical', Terran Buildings are mechanical, Protoss buildings are not.

Answer (score 12):

SCVs cannot repair non-terran structures. They can however be used to repair a variety of Protoss units (Hit Points only, NOT shields):

- Probe
- Stalker
- Sentry
- Immortal
- Colossus
- Observer
- Warp
- Prism
- Phoenix
- Void Ray
- Carrier
- Interceptor
- Mothership

For completeness, here are the list of Terran units that an SCV can repair too:

- SCV (note that SCVs can *also* be repaired by medivacs)
- MULE
- Hellion
- Siege Tank
- Thor
- Viking
- Medivac
- Raven
- Banshee
- Battlecruiser
- Point Defense Drone
- Auto-Turret
- All Terran Buildings

SCVs can not repair anything from Zerg, sorry (although if a zerg player uses neural parasite on a mechanical unit, it can be repaired by an ally's SCV or an SCV that is also NP controlled).

Sources:

http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Mechanical

http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/SCV

Answer (score 1):

No you can't but still there is great synergy between Protos and Terran.

**SCVs** can repair the HP (not shield) of friendly Protos units except Zealot, High Templar and Dark Templar. To heal these biological units, you can use **Medivacs**.

Comment: he was asking about structures

Comment: @Ender - my bad. I changed the answer to more appropriate.